# lodash values of single object to array of objects with fixed key

Tags: arrays, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

I have an object

```
{
    key1:'val1',
    key2:'val2',
    key3:'val3',
    key4:'val4'
}
```

I need to convert it to the following:

```
[
    {key:'val1'},
    {key:'val2'},
    {key:'val3'},
    {key:'val4'}
]
```

The `key` in the final object is fixed.

How do i do this using lodash or underscore? I know I can use `_.values` and then `forEach` on it, but somehow that doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for lodash or underscore. Just map over the `Object.keys()`

```js
var obj = {
    key1:'val1',
    key2:'val2',
    key3:'val3',
    key4:'val4'
};

var newObj = Object.keys(obj).map(function (k) {
    return {
   key: obj[k]
    }
});

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: This is great! Which one do you think is faster / less expensive? The one that @Season posted with lodash or this one?

Comment: I didn't check, but I would always prefer build in js functions over a library if they are doing the same with the same (or less) amount of code. @DushyantBangal

Comment: Can you help me with this one?:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774303/lodash-mapping-keys-from-one-object-with-values-in-array-of-objects

Answer (score 0):

Below is a `lodash` version

```
_.map({
    key1: 'val1',
    key2: 'val2',
    key3: 'val3',
    key4: 'val4'
}, function( value ) { return { key: value }; } );
```

Comment: Can you help me with this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774303/lodash-mapping-keys-from-one-object-with-values-in-array-of-objects