# lodash Mapping Keys from one object with values in array of objects

Tags: arrays, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

**I have the following object:**

```
var kmap={
    key1:"useless",
    key2:"useless",
    key3:"useless"
};
```

**I need to map its keys with values of this array of Objects:**

```
var incoming=[
    {value:"asd"},
    {value:"qwe"},
    {value:"zxc"}
];
```

**Result:**

```
{
    key1:"asd",
    key2:"qwe",
    key3:"zxc",
}
```

**Here's how I'm doing it right now:**

```
var result={};

var keys=Object.keys(kmap);

for(var i=0;i<incoming.length;i++)
{
    result[keys[i]]=incoming[i].value;
}
```

How do I do it using `lodash` or `underscore`. Built-in method would be even better, dont want to do `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using lodash:

```
var result = _.zipObject(_.keys(kmap), _.map(incoming, 'value'))
```

[**zipObject**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.2#zipObject) creates an object given an array of keys and an array of values. The keys we get from `kmap` and the values are plucked from `incoming`.

```js
var kmap={
    key1:"useless",
    key2:"useless",
    key3:"useless"
};

var incoming=[
    {value:"asd"},
    {value:"qwe"},
    {value:"zxc"}
];

var result = _.zipObject(_.keys(kmap), _.map(incoming, 'value'))

document.getElementById('result').textContent = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <pre id="result"></pre>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them with the following function:

```js
var kmap={
    key1:"useless",
    key2:"useless",
    key3:"useless"
   
};

var incoming=[
    {value:"asd"},
    {value:"qwe"},
    {value:"zxc"}
];

function combine(obj1, obj2, propToTake) {
  return Object.keys(obj1).map(function(key, i) {
    return {
       [key]: obj2[i] ? obj2[i][propToTake] : undefined
    }
  });
}

console.log(combine(kmap, incoming, 'value'));
```